# How to set path for client in java6-64 bit, because there no client folder in java 64 bit

Tags: java

In java 6 64-bit there is no client folder to set client for path, so how to set/get it from.

Comment: What do you mean under the "client folder"

Comment: before i used jdk-5,6 32 bit so there is client folder in it but i need to set client for  64 bit so there is no client folder, is there any alternative way to set jre for client in java6 64-bit.  i am going to experiment --- i'll put one folder as client and i'll copy all jre6 content in it, i am searching like this there should be any other alternative, and i'll update.

Answer (score 1):

Many versions do not have a client JVM. If the client folder is missing that means your version did not come with one. Use the server JVM instead.

Comment: That is not working.. i tried . error shows that 'Path' need to set client location.